# Angular - getting json value in console but not in view

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, themoviedb-api

movie/id/external_ids?api_key=myapikey

{"id":335984,"imdb_id":"tt1856101","facebook_id":"BladeRunner2049","instagram_id":"bladerunnermovie","twitter_id":"bladerunner"}

want to display the value of all social ids like facebook, insta and twitter. not sure what's wrong I am doing

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.css']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  movie: Object;
  external_ids: Array<Object>;
  constructor(
    private _moviesServices: MoviesService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute      ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this._moviesServices.getMovie(id).subscribe(movie => {
        this.movie = movie;
      });
      this._moviesServices.getExternalIds(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res.facebook_id);
        this.external_ids = res.external_ids;
      });
    })

  }
}
```

HTML

```
<p  *ngFor="let social of external_ids" class="text-primary" >
        <span *ngIf="social.facebook_id.length > 0" class="mr-3">
      {{social.facebook_id}}
      </span>
    </p>
```

Comment: In this line `console.log(res.facebook_id);` you are printing the facebook_id while in the line below you are saving in your component variable the external_ids property of the json`this.external_ids = res.external_ids;`. Is this correct?

Comment: Did you try only with {{facebook_id}} instead of {{social.facebook_id}} ?

Comment: I thins  you should do ``this.external_ids = res `` inside 2nd subscription

Comment: @LucaRegazzi yes external_ids holds all three social value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to use `ngFor` over an object. `ngFor` can only iterate over arrays. Seems easier for you to just display them directly in the UI using `external_ids.facebook_id` but if you really want to use `ngFor` to show all of them by looping over your object, you can use `Object.keys` to get an array for `ngFor`

First expose `Object.keys` from your component.

```js
objectKeys = Object.keys;
```

Then use this in your HTML

```html
<p *ngFor="let social of objectKeys(external_ids)" class="text-primary">
    {{external_ids[social]}}
</p>
```

I've removed the `ngIf` assuming you want to display all the social ids.

If you want to remove the `id` from your object (since it looks like a user id and not a social id)

```js
this._moviesServices.getExternalIds(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
    const {id, ...external_ids} = res;
    this.external_ids = external_ids;
});
```

**Edit**: Although the above method will work, you can also use the [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe), to convert your object into an array in order to iterate over it. This way you will not need to use `Object.keys`

```html
<p *ngFor="let social of external_ids | keyvalue" class="text-primary">
    {{social.value}}
</p>
```

> Note: The `keyValue` method will work on Angular version 6+

Here is a working example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-for-object).

Comment: Thank you! actually, id is movie id and JSON data I am getting doesn't seem to have key value. I tried above but still not fixed

Comment: this is the error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object at MovieComponent.keys [as objectKeys]

Comment: It sounds like you have missed out something from what I said. I have tested this on StackBlitz. On which line are you getting this error and what exactly have you got on that line?

Comment: error shows on this: <p *ngFor="let social of objectKeys(external_ids)" class="text-primary"> and console says "Cannot destructure property `id` of 'undefined' or 'null'. "

Comment: yes, it worked! thank you so much I just removed external id from the constructor: "     const {id, ...external_ids} = res.external_ids; replaced with "     const {id, ...external_ids} = res;

Comment: the last thing I don't want to display imdb_id field?

Comment: Just do this `const {id, imdb_id, ...external_ids} = res`

Comment: More on destructuring here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: @RRPANDEY - I have added an alternate method to iterate over your object in my answer. This is probably an easier method rather than using `Object.keys`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your **external_ids** to an array of ids. It is easy, using either `Object.keys(external_ids)` or `keys(external_ids)` using [**lodash**'s keys](https://lodash.com/docs/#keys) function.

And **do not forget unsubscribe your subscription**. For it use any of option listed below:

1. make a subscribe inside **ngOnInit** and call **unsubscribe** inside **ngOnDestroy** like this:

```js
subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = someObservable.subscribe(...);
}

ngOnDestory() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

2. inside **ngOnInit** use pipe **takeUntil** from **rxjs/operators** like this:

```js
unsubscribe$ = new Subject<any>();

ngOnInit() {
  someObservable.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
  ).subscribe(...);
}

ngOnDestory() {
   this.unsubscribe$.next(null);
   this.unsubscribe$.complete();
}
```

3. use **async** pipe like this (in this case you don't need unsubscribing):

**ts:**

```js
data$: Observable<object>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.data$ = someObservable;
}
```

**html**:
`{{ data$ | async | json }}`

I prefer and recommend **the second** one 'cause you can use one subject for all of your subscriptions and terminate it at once. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are printing successfully the facebook id on this line

```
console.log(res.facebook_id);
```

you are not passing the facebook_id value to you external_ids on this line

```
this.external_ids = res.external_ids;
```

and that's because facebook_id is not an attribute of external_id, but of res.

So I believe your solution to this problem is this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { MoviesService } from '../movies.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie',
  templateUrl: './movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie.component.css']
})
export class MovieComponent implements OnInit {
  movie: Object;
  external_ids: Array<Object>;
  constructor(
    private _moviesServices: MoviesService,
    private router: ActivatedRoute      ) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe((params) => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this._moviesServices.getMovie(id).subscribe(movie => {
        this.movie = movie;
      });
      this._moviesServices.getExternalIds(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
        console.log(res.facebook_id);
        this.external_ids = res;
      });
    })
  }
}
```

I only changed the line where you pass the response to external_ids.
And you don't need to change the HTML

Comment: thank you! I tried this but seem not working ERROR " Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. "